# Can I use DigitalOcean to host a social app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting, cloud

I'm creating a social app for photo sharing (really simple) using Ruby on Rails. I use a few Rails dependencies and MySQL as database. I also need to use my custom domain already bought.

I have some doubts:

- Will DigitalOcean be enough in case of my app needs to scale fast?
- Can I have access to a shell that allows me to install and change Rails aspects?
- Will I have complete access to MySQL, including backup and other stuff?
- Is there a better solution for a starter application?

Comment: Deploying to [**Heroku**](http://www.heroku.com/) or [**EngineYard**](https://www.engineyard.com/) will help you get your app running quickly, and makes scaling even quite fun. Spend the time you save on setting up and administrating your environment on building your app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to go either a PaaS provider like Heroku, or an IaaS provider like DigitalOcean.

#### PaaS

Less visibility into the actual architecture that runs the app, a little easier to scale, but more expensive. Also, when you have less visibility, you aren't as focused on fine-tuning your code and using simple architectural choices to improve performance without adding complexity.

#### IaaS

You are responsible for everything, which means you will need to spend more time on initial setup and figuring out a few new things; but then you'll be better versed in how your application interacts with the hardware and what elements you will need to tweak to scale.

#### Basic IaaS Setup for Scale

You can guess ahead of time what part of your site will have the hardest time scaling; but at the end of the day, regardless of how much you plan, you will eventually hit a bottleneck. So here are a few simple steps you can take that will delay when you hit the performance wall and also make it easier to scale when you do:

1. **Dedicated DB Instance** - move your DB server to its own virtual machine from the get-go. The workload of the DB server, cache server, and app servers are different and they are best optimized when they handle a single specific task. You can also use all of the resources of the VM for the DB.
2. **Nginx Load Balancer** - now that your DB is on a separate server, you can create your traditional app/web server. I would recommend that you create two web servers and create an Nginx load balancer that can spread the load across these machines. It's more configuration but then when you add server #3, #4, #N it's a simple config change.
3. **Caching!** - Cache everything! It could be something simple like using memcache which is queried before your DB, or it can be creating cache pages for the most commonly hit URLs or partials on your site, but caching will improve your load times dramatically and also let you serve more hits with less servers saving you cash.
4. **Object Store/Content** - If you have a heavy content component, you should use an Object store like Amazon's S3 from the get-go. By integrating this into your app from the start you wont need to re architect this later. It will cost you a bit more money but you also need to consider the headache you are saving yourself from not needing to manage multiple volumes and deal with some of the scaling issues that arise.
5. **Config Management : Puppet/Chef** - Now that you have a couple of different types of servers: DB, Web/App, Load Balancer, Cache - it's a great idea to use Puppet or Chef to set them up. Again you will have a learning curve but that means when you need to add N+1 server to the specific instance type it will take you 2 minutes, instead of 2 hours.

There are of course a lot of other considerations, but the more steps that you take that are forward looking at the beginning, the easier your path to scaling will be. Regardless of how many steps you take, you will still run into scaling issues, so it's important to balance this out in an MVP lean startup approach so you don't spend months making the perfect infrastructure setup, since without traction, it doesn't matter if you have all of the servers since they aren't getting hit with a lot of traffic.

The basic idea behind this write is that your main question is PaaS vs IaaS and if you go the IaaS route DigitalOcean (since I'm a cofounder) is a great choice, but ultimately your biggest wins with an IaaS provider will be around making a few smart decisions as you are setting up your app.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your application can run on a Digitalocean VPS.

- You can scale your Digitalocean VPS whenever you need more recources. (https://www.digitalocean.com/features)
- You will have root access to your VPS. So you can install Rails by yourself and change everything you want.
- Yes.
- Maybe a shared hosting environment with Ruby support will meet your needs.